# What allowed characters for id attribute so that jQuery selector will not throw exception?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a situation where id attribute is entered by end user.
Suppose id for textbox is "11_=11" entered by the user then
html code will look like,

```
<input type="text" id="11_=11">
```

And jQuery selector will be

```
$("#11_=11")
```

But this throws error as unrecognized expression.
I can restrict characters that user enters for id attribute. 
But I don't know which characters creating problem for jQuery selector.
Please help.

Comment: Everything throwing unrecognized expression can be escaped in a selector. `., :, ;, =, (, )..etc.` almost every special character which interferes with jQuery selector should be avoided. You can still escape these by `\\`

Comment: you can try encode the id string, so need not the enter limit。

Comment: As a note, if you are using HTML4, CSS ids cannot begin with a number

Comment: Ya... you can't begin with a number.

Comment: is there any regex that will replace all special characters with "\\"   so that "11_=11" will become "11_\\=11"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [escape those special characters](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) using `\\`

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains [the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

So it will become `$("#11_\\=11")`